# Plotting with small variations along the vertical axis

Tags: plotting, precision-and-accuracy

I can't see the small changes of my function when I plot it. What can I do?

```
r = 4.5;
h = 55;
rho = 10^16;
vol = Pi r*r*h;
n = vol*rho;
ω0 = 508.8*10^12;
γ = 61.54*10^6;
ℏ = 1.054571596*10^-34;(*J s*)
c = 2.99792458*10^9;(*m/s*)

e = 1.60217646263*10^-19;(*C*)
μ0 = 4 Pi*10^-7; (* N/A^2 *)
ϵ0 = (μ0*(c^2))^-1;
μ = 2.9883*10^-29;
u = 3*10 - 3;
ξ = (2 u/ϵ0)^(1/2);
Ω = μ ξ/ℏ; (*Rabi fr^equency*)

W = (2 (Ω^2))/(γ^2);
cte = (2 n (μ^2))/(ξ ℏ γ);

g3[ω_] := cte/(1 + ((4 ((ω - ω0)^2)/γ^2)) + (W));

n3[ω_] := 1 - ((2 (ω - ω0)/γ) g3[ω]);

p5 = Plot[g3[ω], {ω, 3.9*10^14, 6*10^14}, PlotRange -> All]
p6 = 
  Plot[n3[ω], {ω, 3.9*10^14, 6*10^14}, 
    PlotRange -> {{4.7*10^14, 5.4*10^14}, {.9999999, 1.0000001}}]
```

The problem is with plot `p6`, in which the variations are very small and the vertical axis doesn't let me see smaller variations than plot `p5` (2.*10^-29)

Answer (score 1):

Substract `-1` from the n3.

```
n3[\[Omega]_] := -((2 (\[Omega] - \[Omega]0)/\[Gamma]) g3[\[Omega]]);

p5 = Plot[g3[\[Omega]], {\[Omega], 3.9*10^14, 6*10^14}, 
     PlotRange -> All, Mesh -> All, PlotPoints -> 300]
p6 = Plot[n3[\[Omega]], {\[Omega], 4.7*10^14, 5.4*10^14}, Mesh -> All,
     PlotPoints -> 300, 
    Ticks -> {Automatic, {{-10^-24, 
    "1-\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(10\), \(-24\)]\)"}, {0, "1"}, {10^-24,
    "1+\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(10\), \(-24\)]\)"}}}]
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

This answer shows you how to fake a plot of `n3` by plotting

```
m[ω_] := -(2 (ω - ω0)/γ) g3[ω]
```

which is `n3[ω] - 1` but plots nicely about x-axis without having machine arithmetic problems.  Then it is only necessary to relabel the y-axus so that the plot reads as if it were a plot of `n3`.

```
xticks = Table[{i, i/1*^14}, {i, Subdivide[4.8*^14, 5.4*^14, 6]}];
yticks =
 {{-1.*10^-24, HoldForm[1 - 1.*^-24]},
  {-5.*10^-25, HoldForm[1 - 5.*^-25]},
  {5.*10^-25, HoldForm[1 + 5.*^-25]},
  {1.*10^-24, HoldForm[1 + 1.*^-24]}};

p6 =
  Plot[m[ω], {ω, 4.7*10^14, 5.4*10^14},
    PlotPoints -> 75,
    PlotRange -> {Automatic, {-1.25*10^-24, 1.25*10^-24}},
    AxesLabel -> {Row[{"×", HoldForm[10^14]}], ""},
    Ticks -> {xticks, yticks},
    PlotRangeClipping -> False,
    Epilog -> {Text[1., {4.7*^14, 0}, {3, 0}]}]
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have a question, the numbers 
     4.8*^14, 5.4*^14, etc. are missing the number 10? Because M11 marks an error and you write many numbers without the 10 and I don't know what that means

Comment: @ÁulideMartínezTapia. Did you notice the multiplier at the end of the ω-axis. It is to remind the viewer that the ω-axis values are to be multiplied by `10^4`. I did it that way because, with the multiplier shown for each displayed number, the ω-axis labeling gets too crowded. If you prefer, the labeling can be changed. Perhaps you would find `ω/10^4` clearer.

Answer (score 0):

In M11+, you can add [`PrintPrecision`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PrintPrecision) to the [`BaseStyle`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BaseStyle):

```
Plot[
    n3[ω],
    {ω],3.9*10^14,6*10^14},
    PlotRange->{{4.7*10^14,5.4*10^14},{.9999999,1.0000001}},
    BaseStyle->{PrintPrecision->10}
]
```

[image]

Comment: It doesn't work for precision> 15 and i need more than that